# How to find last div if having a text?

Tags: php

I have like this example a `code` :

```
<div>
   <div>
      <p>SOS</p>
        <div>
           <p>searching text</p>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

now i want with php simple `dom parser` searching a text like `SOS` and if `strpos true` echo thats div. my final result like this :

```
<div>
   <p>SOS</p>
   <div>
      <p>searching text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

i wrote this code but doesn't work :

```
<?php
 include('simple_html_dom.php');

 $html = @file_get_html('example code');
 $mytext = 'SOS';

 foreach(@$html->find('div') as $div)
 {
  if(strpos(strtolower($div->innertext),strtolower($mytext)) !== false)
  {
    echo $div->outertext;
    break;
  }  
 }
?>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you're already close, just output the inner text instead then break it once its found

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but the selectors in Simple HTML DOM Parser are, well, simple, and this looks more like a job for **XPath**.

So, if the use of that library is not a requirement, you could as well use libxml, e.g. something along the lines of

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile( 'sample.html' );
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$mytext='SOS';
foreach( $xp->query("//div[./*[text()[contains(.,'$mytext')]]") as $match ) {
  print $dom->saveHTML( $match );
}
?>
```

This is not tested so the code might need a bit of tweaking.